# Transitive project references with build dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have the following projects in my solution (the tree structure indicate which projects reference which other projects):

```
A (.NET Core Web API, C#)
 B (.NET Standard class library, C#)
  X (.NET 4.0 class library, VB)
   Y (.NET 4.0 class library, VB)
    Z (.NET 2.0 class library, VB)
```

The only projects that should be managed from this solution are `A` and `B`. `B` uses some methods from `X` (which comes from elsewhere in our company), while `X` depends on `Y` which again depends on `Z`. All references are project references. (In reality, the hierarchy below `X` is wider/deeper, but the above serves to get the point across.)

I don't want to have unnecessary projects in my solution (which slows things down). At the same time, I want to have VS compile all dependencies in the correct order. AFAIK, all necessary information exists in the csproj/vbproj files, so I don't see a technical reason why VS shouldn't be able to do this if I just add `X` to the solution. But I can only get it to work if I add the entire tree below `X`.

Is there any (sensible) way to set up compilation of all dependent projects without adding the entire project hierarchy to the solution, or is this the way it's supposed to work?